# Creating multiples pandas dataframes as outputs of a function iteration over a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to use the function `itis.hierarchy_full` of the `pytaxize` package in order to retrieve information about a biological species from a specific Id.

The function takes only one values/Id and save all the taxonomic information inside a pandas dataframe that I can edit later.

```
import pandas as pd
from pytaxize import itis
test1 = itis.hierarchy_full(180530, as_dataframe = True)
```

I have something like 800 species Ids, and I want to automate the process to obtain 800 different dataframes.

I have somehow created a test with a small list (be aware, I am a biologist so the code is really basic and maybe inefficient:

```
species = [180530, 48739, 567823]

tx = {}
for e in species2:
    tx[e] = pd.DataFrame(itis.hierarchy_full(e, as_dataframe = True))
```

Now if I input `tx` (I'm using a Jupyter Notebook) I obtain a dictionary of pandas dataframes (I think it is a nested dictionary). And if I input `tx[180530]` I obtain exactly a single dataframe equal to the ones that I can create with the original function.

```
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal
assert_frame_equal(test_180530, sp_180530)
```

Now I can write something to save each result stored in dictionary as a separate dataframe:

```
sp_180530 = tx[180530]
sp_48739 = tx[48739]
sp_567823 = tx[567823]
```

There is a way to automate the process and save each dataframe to a sp_id? Or even better, there is a way to include in the original function where I create tx, to output directly multiple dataframes?

Comment: What goal are you trying to achieve by doing this? Why do you want to give the dataframe a new variable name instead of using the result in the dictionary?

Comment: @NielsHenkens I need to clean and store each dataframe (one per species) in different ways.  For this particular project I need to clean and pivot each dataframe horizontally. ITIS data are stored vertically but I need dataframes where I have a single value (the species name) and then each column is a taxonomical rank (a column form the genus, one for the class, and so on).
I have already pandas code to clean, reformat and merge each single df into a unique dataframe with all the species as rows and with all the taxonomic rankings as columns. The cleaning process works with single df.

Comment: Why then not loop through the dataframes in the dictionary, assign every dataframe in the dictionary to a (the same) temporary dataframe, clean/transform it, save it and go on to the next dataframe in the dictionary? I don't really see the need yet to assign them individual variable names.

Comment: Honestly I'm more comfortable in working with pandas dataframes that with dictionaries (especially nested dicts are new to me). I'll try some iterations directly on the nested dict to see how much I can save it directly in a df without the individual variables.

The major difference is that the singles df are more "granular". I can send or remerge a df with only some variables, maybe create a df only from the species with a certain similar id and so on. It seemed to me as more "generalised".

Comment: You don't really need "to work with dictionaries". You can just use the individual dataframes in the dict. See my "answer" below for an example. You can do whatever you need to do to `df_temp` (which is just a pandas dataframe) and then go on to the next one...

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked, but to be able to elaborate a bit more on working with the dataframes in the dictionary... To work with the dictionary, loop over the dict and then use every contained dataframe one by one...

```
for key in tx.keys():
    df_temp = tx[key]

    # < do all your stuff to df_temp .....>

    # Save the dataframe as you want/need (I assume as csv for here)    
    df_temp.to_csv(f'sp_{key}.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done just that and at least I've saved in csv the full taxonomy for all the species.
Now I've to figure how to optimise the code but this is a great start!